# Replace all values in dataframe from values in data.table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am fairly new to R and am trying to replace values in my data.frame named `df` from corresponding values in a data.table called `dtb`. My data.table is simply a count of all unique values in my data.frame and looks as such:

```
df
  fruits
1 apple
2 pear
3 banana
4 apple
5 banana  


dtb
     fruits    N
1    apple     2
2    pear      1
3    banana    2
```

I wish to replace my original data.frame values with the counts based upon the name. For output would look like this:

```
df
  fruits
1 2
2 1
3 2
4 2
5 2
```

I have tried to look through observations and check if it is in the fruits column of the data table but am struggling. Could anyone help me here? Thanks

Comment: It's very similar to the `VLOOKUP` functionality, you can read how to implement it in `R` with `merge()` [here](https://www.rforexcelusers.com/vlookup-in-r/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`join()` functions](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html) from `dplyr` package and then [select and rename](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html) the new column:

```r
# 1. join by "fruits" column, i.e. create a new corresponding N column
# 2. select only column N and rename it to "fruits"
df %>%
  left_join(dtb, by = "fruits") %>%
  select(fruits = N)
#>   fruits
#> 1      2
#> 2      1
#> 3      2
#> 4      2
#> 5      2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(fruits = c("apple", "pear", "banana", "apple", 
"banana")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5"))

dtb <- structure(list(fruits = c("apple", "pear", "banana"), N = c(2L, 
1L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000021f51801ef0>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your data table into a simple map:

```
df$fruits <- sapply(df$fruits, function(x) setNames(dtb$N, dtb$fruits)[x])
```

which gives:

```
> df
  fruits
1      2
2      2
3      1
4      2
5      1
```

**Data**

```
dtb <- data.table::as.data.table(read.table(text="fruits    N
1    apple     2
2    pear      1
3    banana    2", header=TRUE))

df <- read.table(text="fruits
1 apple
2 pear
3 banana
4 apple
5 banana", header=TRUE)
```